# Why + operator has higher priority than * in this Python example?

Tags: python, tuples, operator-precedence

Suddenly I have came across the following code example:

```
def foo(a, b, c):
    return a + b + c

d = foo(*(1, 2) + (3,))
print(d)
```

This code is valid both for Python 2.7.17 and 3.6.9. The output is 6.
So it seems that the code is equivalent to the following:

```
def foo(a, b, c):
    return a + b + c

d = foo(*((1, 2) + (3,)))
print(d)
```

**`*` makes tuple unpacking here, but why is it done after the concatenation of two tuples?**

But I have strong evidence that + operator should have lower priority than * according to the [official documentation about operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) (although, it mentions * only for multiplication).

Can anybody explain the reason of this?

Comment: The `*` operator here is doing tuple-unpacking, not multiplication

Comment: @rdas Yes, I see, but why is it done for the concatenation of tuples?

Comment: Because unpacking the first tuple and then concatenating the second to… what exactly…? …make little sense?

Comment: It isn't done for the concatenation of tuples, its to unpack the tuples values into the function's parameters

Comment: How could the `+` be done after the unpacking? The result of an argument unpacking is not a value, so either unpacking should have lower precedence, or this should be a syntax error. Do you have an argument for why a syntax error would be better?

Comment: Put another way, what alternative behaviour did you think this code might/should have, and why?

Comment: @kaya3 I think it should be a syntax error, because *(a, b) is unpacked tuple, and (c,) is a tuple. From my evidence, we can't make a sum of these two objects of quite different nature.

Comment: foo(*((1, 2) + (3,))) is equivalent to foo(1,2,3)

Comment: *"\*(a, b) is unpacked tuple"* — There's no such thing as an "unpacked tuple". It's not a type or something you can assign to anything. Argument unpacking is a mechanism of calling a function and cannot be separated from it. The `*` here isn't an operator that produces a value.

Comment: The ``*`` unpacking isn't an operator, since it does not produce a value. It is not related to the ``*`` multiplication operator, other than sharing a symbol (just how ``@`` is used for decoarators and ``__matmul__``). Whatever precedence the ``*`` operator has is completely irrelevant for unpacking.

Comment: @deceze. Thanks. Seems that this is an answer

Comment: `1*2` is syntactic sugar for `int.__mul__(1, 2)`. There is no "unary multiplication" operator.